# How to get data from mysql database to Unity for Augmented Reality?

Tags: database, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, virtual, vuforia

I know how to create AR application with Unity3d and Vuforia and I made Android application without any problem, but how can i connect my AR app to my website with php+mysql? For example when user hold their phone on target image it will show the data from website in realtime.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your target is AR do not imply any change, just work as if you were working on an Android App.

So you need to call to your endpoint or your local php files with [UnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/es/530/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html) and do something like this to make a GET petition:

```
private IEnumerator GetRequest(string url)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        else
        {
            //Show results as text
            print(www.downloadHandler.text);
            //Or retrieve results as binary data
            byte[] results = www.downloadHandler.data;
            Debug.Log("Get Request complete!");
            //Do your stuff with the data
        }
    }
}
```

This means that you have to know if your backend files (your php's) are stored in your client or your backend side. I'm aware that the best practice (the secure one) is to store it on your backend, but keep in mind that you can also try having it on your client, like Firebase SDK works.